# Please choose another workspase as /usr is currently used

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project created in eclipse for EE developers v 2020 09 in the centos7 server. the project is closed suddenly when I reopen it again an error appears (Please choose another workspace as /usr is currently used).

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the .lock file in your .metadata folder from your workspace. I had the same issue a while ago.